# I am facing Range Error when I fetch data from JSON file

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a function to fetch data from json file and I show that data to one page when ever my fetch function run it show an erorr for the time till Json fetch that is  3 to 4 second after that data fetch and show succesfully but that error show on screen is very awkward.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(News1());

class News1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      title: "Flutter",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  void fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('jsonfilelinkhere');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    return Scaffold(

      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50 ,right: 50),
        child:ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(data[3]['Head']),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(data[0]['Description']),
            ),
            Image.network(data[0]['ImgUrl']),

          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also tell us what's the error?

Comment: Range Error (index) invalid value valid value range is empty 3

Comment: Please paste full stacktrace in the question itself.

Comment: I try to  run my fetch function on other screen, in each of the screen where i run fetch function this error shows for 3 to 4 second and than everything is normal.

Comment: I am unable to post the stack trace due to  words  limit

Comment: Error is due to this line child: Text(data[0]['Head']),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `fetchData()` function is asynchronous, so your app tap the back of your function saying "hi, `fetchData()` start to work!!" but your app goes on minding its own job.

And you gave this job for it:

```
              child: Text(data[3]['Head']),
```

so your app will hit this line of code while your `data` variable still is an empty list.

You have to prepare it for this situation. You can prepare the default value of the data or you can check if it's empty in the Widgets that depends on it.

Comment: I was looking for the solution that how to do solve it, by the way thanks I made sure about my error  with the help of your answer thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

hope you got your answer. In case you can make a check that while your array is equal to null show `CircularProgressIndicator(),` else show data. If you are unable to do so I can share the code for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You encountered that error as you displayed that data before it could actually load.

Use `FutureBuilder` to solve your issue.

**Example code:**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(News1());

class News1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      title: "Flutter",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    final response = await http.get('jsonfilelinkhere');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        return json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    return Scaffold(

      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50 ,right: 50),
        child:FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        future: fetchData, // async work
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
           switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
             case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Center(child: Text('Loading....'));
             default:
               if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return Text("Error!");
               else{
              data = snapshot.data;
              return ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(data[3]['Head']),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text(data[0]['Description']),
            ),
            Image.network(data[0]['ImgUrl']),

          ],
        )}
            }
         },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you put it into full code ? I am confuse where to put this

Comment: The argument type 'void Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future'

Comment: Still not working. by the way very very thanks I do not know where is problem in my code but you do effort thanks.

Comment: The argument type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future'

Comment: ok no issue thanks Son of Stackoverflow.  I think we can handle this error by fetching data on splash screen loading time which is 3 second and just show the data on req screen.

Comment: Did the above code solve your issue? Like what error did you encounter?

Comment: The argument type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future'

Comment: Check the code again..Is it still giving the same error?